# Absolute positioned DIV to be 100% of body height

Tags: html, css, css-position

I would like to have a div that covers the entire body of a page, even if the content has to be scrolled.

The typical approach is to use an absolutely positioned div while setting 100% height on html and body.

However, if there is other content on the page that is longer than what fits on screen, my 100% height div only covers the visible area of the window and does not stretch all the way until the end of the page.

Example: http://jsbin.com/wuqezaceteme/1/

CSS:

```
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

body {
  position:relative;
}

.wrapper {
  position:absolute; /* can't use fixed */
  background:yellow;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.box {
  height:2200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
 Scroll down (yellow box does not go to bottom when scrolling)
 </div>

 <div class="box">box</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Remove `height:100%` from `body, html`.

Comment: Can i ask you why can not use fixed?

Comment: @lolka_bolka I can't use fixed, because my wrapper will actually contain another div that I need to remain static relative to the scrolling content.

Answer (score 9):

This may help somebody else since this is an old question that seems to be answered.

The main problem is that your div is bound to the viewport rather then the body.
Since you want it to be bound to the body use:-

```
    body {
        position: relative;
    }
```

Also do not add height:100% to the body or html (that is not needed).
That should do it. Now your .wrapper div will be 100% to your body. Even if you scroll the page it will remain 100% since it is bound to the body.

Answer (score 3):

Your body have a default `height:100%` which is the initial height of your window you need to make the height auto either you need to remove it from your style

```
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  <--height:100%;--> Removed
  width:100%;
}
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/wm0u1t4s/)**

Comment: The problem with removing the height from the body tag is that the div will not cover the entire window if the contents are smaller. Try chaining the height of the .box to 200px to see what I mean.